# How to save data to useState hook after clicking checkbox input and displaying it on a different table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two tables, one shows all the data from the API (all products table). Each table data has a checkbox input. When a particular checkbox is clicked, I want that data field to be shown on the other table (selected products table).

I am using jsonplaceholder/users API for demo purpose.

According to my code, all the API data is being shown on the selected product table.
I want only the specific data which I have checked using the checkbox input.

States and Functions

```js
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
const [results, setResults] = useState([])

const handleAPI = async (url) => {
        try {
            let fetchData = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
            let data = await fetchData.json();
            setApiData(data);

            const result = data.filter((user) => {
                return (
                    url &&
                    user &&
                    user.name &&
                    user.name.toLowerCase().includes(url)

                )
            })
            // console.log(result)
            setResults(result)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleAPI()
    }, [])


    const handleSearch = (value) => {
        setInput(value);
        handleAPI(value);
    }
```

All Product Table

```
{results.map((res) => (
    <tr key={res.name} >
      <td className='flex items-center py-4'>
         <input onClick={() => setIsActive(true)} type="checkbox" className='w-[19px] h-[19px] mr-              [0.8rem] cursor-pointer' />
         <div className='flex items-center gap-3'>
           <img src={avatar} alt="avatar" />
           <div>
            <div className='text-sm font-medium'>{res.name}</div>
            <div className='text-sm text-[#667085]'>{res.company.name}</div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </td>
       <td className='text-sm'>₹160</td>
       <td className='text-xs'>&#8226; Not Available</td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Selected Product Table

```
 {isActive && results.map((r, id) => (
                                    
   <tr>
    <td className='flex items-center py-4'>
     <div className='flex items-center gap-3'>
       <img src={avatar} alt="" />
       <div>
         <div className='text-sm font-medium'>{r.name}</div>
         <div className='text-sm text-[#667085]'>{r.company.name}</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </td>

    <td className='text-sm'>₹160</td>
  </tr>
 )                                   
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use should use an array state to hold index of item you've checked,
then use props hidden to check that selected item have index in array state

```
//States & Functions

const [selectedArray, setSelectedArray] = useState([])

//All Product Table 

<input onClick={() => setSelectedArray([...selectedArray, index]) 

//Selected Product Table: <tr hidden={!selectedArray.include(index)}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).